# React-Moment- Parsing ISO 8601 Time Left Into Readable Format

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, ebay-api

I'm trying to take the 'timeLeft field from the eBay API and turn it into something that looks normal, like 3 Hours, 10 Minute and 5 seconds left.

The data looks something like this: P3DT6H28M15S

I'm trying to use the React Moment module but can't figure out exactly how to do this.

This is my latest test:

```
 <Moment format="h:mm:ss">
                {card.sellingStatus && card.sellingStatus[0].timeLeft}
              </Moment>
```

But this is returning 'invalid date'.

I also try the following code just to see what HTML output looks like, but i'm trying a different output field

`<Moment>{card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime}</Moment>`

note that endTime looks like this

`2019-11-09T19:45:32.000Z`

but the above code is generating the same exact value for each item

`Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500`

even though all of the endTime fields are different

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So i mostly accomplished what I needed by using the react-timeago npm module.

```
 <TimeAgo
                date={new Date(
                  card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].startTime
                ).toLocaleDateString()}
              />
```